# How do I add weapon bones to Autorig Pro?

Tags: add-on, bones, auto-rig-pro

I am using Autorig Pro.
How can I create a weapon bone on a bone made in Autorig Pro and parent the bone to the hand?

Comment: I guess you can either create a new bone in the existing armature (for example duplicate the hand bone) or simply parent the object to an existing bone of your armature (like the hand), the object itself can be part of the character but it also can be a separate object

Answer (score 0):

Auto-Rig Pro organizes bones by layers. That's what you need to specify.

While in Auto-Rig Pro Edit Mode, Shift+A to add a bone. Name it the way Auto-Rig understands names :

- name_ref.x if it's in the center.
- name_ref.l if it's left, and r if it's right.

Select those newly created bones and specify the armature layer they need to be part of to be taken into account as base armature bones : 2nd layer, bottom left.

(All explained in the official documentation).

[image]by pressing M :